Manually setting variable on a talend subjob
I've got a main job (a) that sets the reference date for the extraction of some data and a sub job (b) that take the reference date from a and does the extraction.
Is there a way to launch a from terminal but force the use of a different reference date without changing any of the job?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

After you build your job in the studio, you have a folder with different scripts (sh, ps1, bat, ...)
So for example I have this job with a context variable :

The just print the value of the context variable.
By default the variable is this is a test 1
And when you execute the job with the commandline it prints the default variable :

But you can force the value of that variable using the --context_param
So to execute the job with the commandline you use :
J_TEST_CTX_VAR_run.bat --context_param test_var="This is a test 2"


So when you execute your job you just have to change your variable value
Hope this helps
